# Statistics on Hot, Cool, and Archive Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have Azure Storage files (blobs) in various states of Hot, Cool, and Archive. However, I have no idea how many files are in each tier or how much space they are taking up or the cost per tier.

Does anyone know how I can get this information either programmatically or through the Azure Portal? So far the portal only shows monthly totals for *all* files, size, and cost.

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the `Metrics` blade you can use the following selection for a metric:

```
Metric Namespace: Blob
Metric: Blob Capacity or Blob Count
```

Then you can add a filter and filter on the `Blob Tier`. That should give you a good insight on the total space used and the amount of blobs for each tier. Using the Azure Calculator you can then easily calculate what the storage costs.